# sonar maven plugin fails to import project

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to import my project on a remote server via maven plugin but a got the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar 
(default-cli) on project prj: Error 405 on 
https://sonarqubevc.scalefocus.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=bg.prj.commerce:prj&projectName=prj%20Application :
{"errors":[{"msg":"HTTP method POST is required"}]}
```

The version of the server is - SonarQube version: 6.3.0

Any ideas? Is it a bug that I hit or there is some misconfiguration on my side?

Thx

Comment: Solved the problem. It was a proxy configuration that changed POST requests with GET requests